# Json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structure while taking values from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Error is coming while hitting api

```
  createUserProfile=async()=>{
  try {
    let response = await fetch(baseUrl + 'edituserprofilesave', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        hash: this.state.hash,
        timestamp:this.state.timestamp,
        id:this.state.id,
        firstName:this.state.textFirstName,
        lastName:this.state.textLastName,
        picture: this.state.avatarSource.uri

      }),
    });
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    // alert("my response" + JSON.stringify(responseJson))
    alert("success")
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
}
```

I know where error is coming..It is not taking textFirstName and textLastName which i am getting from here..

```
           <FloatingLabelInput
          label="First Name*"
          onChange={value => {
            this.setState({ textFirstName: value });
          }}
          style={[
            styles.FloatingLabelInputStyle,
            { borderBottomColor: this.state.firstNameBorder }
          ]}
        />
```

and similarly textLast name ..I am updating state value but i don't know why it is throwing this error ..
Than you in advance

Comment: What is the value sent in the `onChange` event of `FloatingLabelInput`? Is it a string or an event object?

Comment: Using onChangeText instead of onChanged has solved my problem